# May sick Jews eat before Davening shacharit

Tags: halacha, food, shacharis-morning-prayer, choleh-sick, orach-chaim

According to Halacha is it permissible for sick Jews to eat before shacharit? Or is it prohibited just  like it is normally?

Comment: This question is asked here, and the specific answer to your question is in the first paragraph. It goes on to explain that there are in fact more leniencies than just leniencies. https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/932599/jewish/Eating-Before-Praying.htm#:~:text=Indeed%2C%20the%20Code%20of%20Jewish,exception%20to%20this%20is%20water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Orach Chaim 89:4](https://shulchanarukh.alhatorah.org/Full/Orach_Chayyim/89/4#e0n6), it is permissible even if one just thinks it will aid in his prayer if he eats or drinks. Everyone on the page agrees, although the Mishna Berurah takes a slightly more stringent opinion saying that one may eat only if one is very hungry.

Answer (score 0):

A sick person should eat before praying in order to have the strength to pray as in explained in Rambam laws of prayer and priestly blessing chapter 5 law 2

"...A person who is ill may pray even while lying on his side, provided he is able to have the proper intention. Similarly, one who is thirsty or hungry is considered as one who is ill. [Therefore,] if he is able to concentrate properly he should pray. If not, he should not pray until he has eaten or drunk."